# How are open subsets and relatively open subsets different from each other?

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

To my understanding, if we have a set $U$ and a $A\subset U$ then $A$ is relatively open to $U$ if $\exists$ and open set $\Omega\subset U$ s.t $A=\Omega \cap U$. But also a subset of $U$ is open $\iff$ it is relatively open so would it isn't wrong to say that $\Omega = A$ so why do we need to define the idea of openness relative to a set?

Comment: $U$ is open if it is relatively open to what set? The thing about relative openness is says something about how we are considering the set in question.

Comment: I missed out part of the question! Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take for example $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology. $A = [0, 1)$ is not an open, but if you take $U = [0, 2]$, you see that $A$ is relatively open with respect to $U$, because $[0, 1) = [0, 2] \cap (-1, 1)$, which is the intersection of $U$ and an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Oh!! so $\Omega$ itself doesn't need to be a subset of $U$? Would it also be that my assumption $A$ is open iff $A$ is relatively open in $U$ is false then?

Comment: No, $\Omega$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, in this case. More generally, if you had $U \subseteq V$ (both topological spaces), then $\Omega$ is a subset of $V$. This is known as induced or subspace topology.
Yes, it's false, the example I showed above gives you a set not open in $\mathbb{R}$, but that's open in the subspace topology of $[0, 2].

Answer (score 0):

Consider $ \mathbb R$ with usual topology and $(0,1]$ with subspace topology wrt $\mathbb R$

Note that $(1/2,1]$ is open in $(0,1]$ but not open in $\mathbb R$

i.e. $(1/2,1]$ is relatively open in $(0,1]$

Comment: So would it be that in your example $\Omega$ = A = (1/2, 1] in this case?

Comment: Actually you have phrased your question wrongly. Relative openness makes sense when you want to talk about openness of set in some subset of topological space.